# Study the existence of $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\(x,y)\neq(0,0)}\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{3}-2\sin(x^{2}y^{\beta})\cos(x+2y)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying the existence of this limit for $\alpha$,$\beta\in\mathbb R$ but I've found several problems.

First of all I started separating $\beta$ into 3 cases: $\beta>0,\beta=0,\beta<0$.

CASE $\beta>0$: the argument of sin tend to $0$, so I can use (?) the asymptotic $sin(x^{2}y^{\beta}) \sim x^{2}y^{\beta} $ and the limit becomes $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\(x,y)\neq(0,0)}\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{3}-2(x^{2}y^{\beta})\cos(x+2y)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

Now,  $-1\le\cos(x+2y)\le1$ so the limit is restricted to $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\(x,y)\neq(0,0)}\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{3}-2(x^{2}y^{\beta})}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\le\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\(x,y)\neq(0,0)}\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{3}-2(x^{2}y^{\beta})\cos(x+2y)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\le\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\(x,y)\neq(0,0)}\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{3}+2(x^{2}y^{\beta})}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

If I use the polar coordinate I find: the limit exists and is equal to $0$ if $\alpha>-1$, doesn't exist if $\alpha=-1$ and is equal to $\infty$ if $\alpha<-1$.

CASE $\beta=0$: the limit doesn't exist.

CASE $\beta<0$: we have to divide into other cases the limit. We consider the argument of $\sin(x^{2}y^{\beta})$. If $\beta=-2$ the limit doesn't exist because $lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}}$ doesn't exist. But here I find some difficulties to continue: what about the x-axis? Do I have to exclude it from the domain? And what about $-2<\beta<0$ and $\beta < -2$? Any suggestions? Is it correct what I've done?

Comment: If $\alpha <0$ the limit does NOT exist.

Comment: you can study $f(x,x)$ to rule out $\beta\le 0$, try to find first as much divergence cases as possible to reduce the range of $\alpha,\beta$ before exploring the corner cases (which imho are a nightmare...)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet may I ask you why?

Comment: @zwim thanks for the hint. I will try that way

Comment: If $\beta\ge 0>\alpha$ and $x,y>0$ then we have $\frac {|-2x^2y^{\beta}\cos (x+2y)|}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac {|-2x^2y^{\beta}|}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac {|-2x^2y^{\beta}|}{x^2}=2y^{\beta}$ which is bounded as $x,y\to 0^+.$ But if $\alpha <0$ and $x>0$ and $y=x^{|\alpha |/3}$ then the other term $\frac {x^{\alpha}y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\frac {1}{x^2+y^2} \to\infty$  as $x,y\to 0^+.$